# Generating logos using latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, png

Is there a package to generate logos given some text and parameters?

So,

```
\begin{logo}
  \background-color green
  \text-in-logo Drummer Society
  \text-color orange
\end{logo}
```

Or a variation of it will work and produce a jpg/ png file?

If there is no such package, can something be implemented in tikz?

Comment: What's the logo ?

Comment: Hmm, orange on green, really snazzy...

Comment: @Brent.Longborough just as an example. Could change to black and white :)

Answer (score 10):

This is not exactly an answer to the question so much as a demonstration of one line of possible exploration. It adapts some code I made earlier and shows how to create a logo consisting of a central focus - an image or letters or whatever - with lettering arranged in a circle around it.

I present a draft logo for the TeX Society for the Protection of Feline Persons, which uses an image of TUG-loving cats, and another for the Ancient Drummer Society of Milton Keynes, which takes the key initials D and S for the focus.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{rgb,x11names,dvipsnames,svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{PTSerifCaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \i/\j/\k in {black/black/45mm,white/black/35mm} \path [inner color=\i, outer color=\j, draw=black, line width=1.5pt, double distance=.75mm, double=white] circle (\k);
  \path [decorate, decoration={text effects along path, text={\TeX{} \textbullet{} SOCIETY \textbullet{} FOR \textbullet{} THE \textbullet{} PROTECTION \textbullet{} OF \textbullet{} FELINE \textbullet{} PERSONS \textbullet{}}, text effects/.cd, text along path, fit text to path, characters={font=\LARGE, text=white}}] (90:38mm) arc (90:-270:38mm);
  \node {\includegraphics[height=55mm] {cath-eistedd-tug}};
  \begin{scope}[xshift=100mm]
  \foreach \i/\j/\k in {black/black/45mm,white/black/35mm} \path [inner color=\i, outer color=\j, draw=black, line width=1.5pt, double distance=.75mm, double=white] circle (\k);
  \path [decorate, decoration={text effects along path, text={ANCIENT \textbullet{} DRUMMER \textbullet{} SOCIETY \textbullet{} OF \textbullet{} MILTON \textbullet{} KEYNES \textbullet{}\ }, text effects/.cd, text along path, fit text to path, characters={font=\LARGE, text=white}}] (90:38mm) arc (90:-270:38mm);
  \node [scale=5, font=\Huge, xshift=-.5mm, yshift=1mm] {$\mathcal{D}$};
  \node [scale=5, font=\Huge, xshift=1mm, yshift=-1mm] {$\mathcal{S}$};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demonstration logos]

Logos for the TeX Society for the Protection of Donkeys and the TeX Society for the Prevention of Cruelty to Ducks are available elsewhere on this site. The code for the TUG-loving cats is available on Meta.

Comment: The green and orange variants I leave as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Yikes, Voldemort-cats! Awesome, though.

Comment: Can we have a “Constantinopolitanischerdudelsackspfeifenmachersgesellschafft” logo, please?

Comment: @egreg What does that mean?

Comment: @cfr Don't you know "A Connecticut Yankee at King Arthur's Court"? And surely you didn't read Appendix H of the TeXbook.

Comment: @egreg In some sense. I think I tried to read it once and gave up, but I might be mistaken. (I might have tried to read it and not given up or I might not have tried to read it.) If I did, it was a long time ago. As for the TeX book, I'm still trying to figure out how to print my first document on the 'printer'.

Comment: @RunarTrollet What's wrong with my cats? I'm don't recall Voldemort having cats at all, but I'm certainly no expert.

Answer (score 6):

I doubt, that there is a special package for generating logos in general, because logos are too different. Some only need some text, like the LaTeX logo, some are quite artificial with lots of graphical elements.

Class `standalone` can be a convenient class for creating standalone documents. It can be compiled to PDF and converted further to image formats.

An simple example, generated by pdflatex and ghostscript:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[
    fill=green,
    text=orange,
    font=\sffamily,
  ]{Drummer Society};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

In this case, there is no need for TikZ:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\colorbox{green}{\color{orange}\sffamily Drummer Society}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result without TikZ]

Comment: Even shorter is possible `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} \begin{document} \tikz\node[fill=green,text=orange] {Drummer Society}; \end{document}`

Comment: @HenriMenke I thought the same, but decided against. The pseudo code in the question uses an environment. (The example could have defined environment `logo` on the base of `tikzpicture`.) The environment form is more flexible, when other graphical elements are added. The one-command form looks nicer, agreed; but I think, the environment form is easier to use for beginners.

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with the classic `\fcolorbox`?

> [image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\logo[4]{{%
\fboxsep.3em\fboxrule1.5pt
\fcolorbox{#1}{#2}{\sffamily\bfseries\color{#3} #4}}}
\begin{document}
My logo: \logo{green!50}{green!25}{orange}{Drummer Society}
\bigskip
Other logo: \logo{red!30}{cyan!25}{orange}{\colorbox{yellow}{fcolorbox} rulez! }
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With a `tcbox` from  `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcbox{\logo}{nobeforeafter, notitle, sharp corners,
    colframe=orange,
    colback=orange!30,
    fontupper=\sffamily\bfseries,
    colupper=green!30!black,
    tcbox raise base}

\begin{document}
This is the logo: \logo{Drummer Society}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With ConTeXt MKIV and Metafun

```
\startMPpage
  color orange; orange := (1,.5,0);
  picture pic; pic := textext("Drummer Society");
  fill boundingbox pic xyscaled(1.2,1.5) withcolor green;
  draw pic withcolor orange;
\stopMPpage
```

[image]